# java.util.Currency.getInstance throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I am just trying my hands around with `java.util.Currency`, but for few currency codes its throwing me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

this is my simple code

```
java.util.Currency c = java.util.Currency.getInstance(code);
```

as per java doc

> public static Currency getInstance(String currencyCode)

```
Returns the Currency instance for the given currency code.

Parameters:
    currencyCode - the ISO 4217 code of the currency 
Returns:
    the Currency instance for the given currency code 
Throws:
    NullPointerException - if currencyCode is null 
    IllegalArgumentException - if currencyCode is not a supported ISO 4217 code.
```

I am getting this exception for few codes and few of them are

1. UYI
2. COU
3. TMT

as per [ISO_4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217), all above codes are official ISO 4217 currency names, i am not sure why i am getting this exception in this case?
Do i need to do something else or need to pass some other information to JVM to get correct values?
any help to clear my confusion is really appreciable or can point me to the *ISO 4217 currency* which java doc is pointing as i can see above codes in ISO 4217 list so its possible i am looking at wrong documents/references.

In order to provide more insights here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at CurrencyTest1.main(CurrencyTest1.java:10)
```

### and Java version

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace and mention which JDK version are you running?

Comment: @Augusto:i have updated my post, have a look.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with Java 1.7 for the currency codes you mentioned.

Comment: @roelandvanbeek:that's strange!! seems like those are not supported currency codes under *ISO 4217*.

Comment: Just check your currencies against `Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()`. On my box TMT is available, the others are not.

Comment: @home:sorry i am still with JDK6 :(

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi: Hm, did not recognize that. sorry.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting problem.

Both COU and UYI are not real currencies. COU is the old Venezuelan currency (not in use anymore) and UYI is an indexed currency, probably used by banks to sort out exchange rates.

In java 1.7.0_u7, the currecy *TMT* works fine. TMT was introduced in 2009, so it makes sense that Java 6 doesn't know that code.

Comment: please see my edit. TMT is a new code, so it makes sense that is not available on java 6

Answer (score 1):

For Uruguay `UYU` is working fine instead of `UYI` and `COP` instead of `COU` for Columbia `TMT` is not working for me also.

Comment: yes its there in my list and for this its working fine.i am not sure about UYI though

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
For me this works:

```
 Currency curr = java.util.Currency.getInstance("UYU");
 System.out.println("Currency code:" + curr.getCurrencyCode());
```

`UYI` is not in the ISO 4217 standard, here is a list: http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php

Comment: Can you try with this line of code `java.util.Currency.getInstance("UYI");` and update what is the outcome?