# java.util.Currency and ISO 4217 standards

Tags: java, currency

Following from my previous question [java-util-currency-getinstance-throwing-illegalargumentexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761846/java-util-currency-getinstance-throwing-illegalargumentexception), I was looking at the source code of [java.util.Currency](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Currency.java#Currency.0instances)

I saw the following snippet of code:

```
static {
  AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
    public Object run() {
      String homeDir = System.getProperty("java.home");
      try {
        String dataFile = homeDir + File.separator +
        "lib" + File.separator + "currency.data";
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(dataFile)));
        if (dis.readInt() != MAGIC_NUMBER) {
          throw new InternalError("Currency data is possibly corrupted");
        }
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
        if (false) {
          // look for the properties file for overrides
          try {
            File propFile = new File(homeDir + File.separator +
            "lib" + File.separator +
            "currency.properties");
            //more code 
            
          }
```

I was wondering about the location of `currency.data` or `currency.properties` as I am unable to find any such files inside `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib`.

On looking under rt.jar I can see a class, `CurrencyData`, which defined a few entries but not sure how it is related to `java.util.Currency`.

I was looking at `public static Currency getInstance(String currencyCode) {}` to see how it checks if the given currency code is under ISO 4217 list or not.  `CurrencyData.properties` looks like the file which is being used to store and pass on this information [Update currency data to the latest ISO 4217 standard](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7066203)

Hope to get some more information on this. Currently I am using following Java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I have created an enhanced ISO 4217 enumeration (and other ISO enums as well). The code is available there:
https://github.com/scout-2766/Iso4J/blob/master/README.md (free of charge)

Answer (score 0):

The source code you have linked to is OpenJDK 6, however you are using Oracle Java 6. The source code for Oracle Java 6 does not reference these currency files, hence they will not be present in your installation.

Bear in mind that OpenJDK branched from Oracle Java 7 (which *does* reference those files in the `Currency` class). OpenJDK 6 was created by stripping code from OpenJDK 7 until it matched the Java 6 specification (see [this link for info](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/01/jdk-openjdk-icedtea)). Clearly this particular chunk of code survived the back-port.

I suspect that if you install OpenJDK 6, you will find the files. Similarly, my Oracle Java 7 installation has those files.

Note that Oracle Java 6 appears to store the currency data in a package-private `java.util.CurrencyData` class.

Comment: I was looking at my JDK rt.jar and no such property found there.I am wondering where Oracle's keep information about currency code information as per ISO

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi See the last paragraph in my edited answer above. I would recommend you acquire the Oracle 6 source and have a look.